# Convert list<ClsObj1> to List<anonymous type obj> where ClsObj1 having a List<ClsObj2> C#

Tags: c#

I have to send a `List<DTOs>` to a WebApi endpoint which is used to render the same in the UI in table format. The Client is asking for an output similar to `List<anonimous type obj>`.

For that I am trying to convert `list<ClsObj1>` to `List<anonimous type obj>` where `ClsObj1` has a `List<ClsObj2>`.

I have tried googling the same but not able to find suitable solution.

This is my Class Model DTOs

```cs
public class SPCRawDataDTO
{
    public DateTime ShiftDate { get; set; }
    public string ShiftName { get; set; }
    public string WorkCode { get; set; }
    public string WorkDesc { get; set; }
    public string GroupType { get; set; }
    public List<SPCDynamicSpecValues> SpecValues { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}

public class SPCDynamicSpecValues
{
    public string PointName { get; set; }
    public decimal SpecValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is the JSON O/P Data for the Above DTO

```
[
    {
        "shiftDate": "2019-08-30T00:00:00",
        "shiftName": "Shift A",
        "workCenterCode": "04INDLGC",
        "workCenterDesc": "CASTING",
        "groupType": "Material",
        "specValues": [
            { "pointName": "W1", "specValue": 242.000 },
            { "pointName": "W2", "specValue": 234.000 },
            { "pointName": "W3", "specValue": 250.000 },
            { "pointName": "W4", "specValue": 236.000 },
            { "pointName": "W5", "specValue": 248.000 } ],
        "remarks": "OK"
    },
    {
        "shiftDate": "2019-08-30T00:00:00",
        "shiftName": "Shift A",
        "workCenterCode": "WCode",
        "workCenterDesc": "WDesc",
        "groupType": "Material",
        "specValues": [
            { "pointName": "W1", "specValue": 238.000 },
            { "pointName": "W2", "specValue": 230.000 },
            { "pointName": "W3", "specValue": 246.000 },],
        "remarks": "OK"
    },
    {
        "shiftDate": "2019-08-30T00:00:00",
        "shiftName": "Shift A",
        "workCenterCode": "WCode",
        "workCenterDesc": "WDesc",
        "groupType": "Material",
        "specValues": [
            { "pointName": "W2", "specValue": 246.000 },
            { "pointName": "W3", "specValue": 232.000 },
            { "pointName": "W4", "specValue": 238.000 },
            { "pointName": "W5", "specValue": 230.000 },
            { "pointName": "W6", "specValue": 244.000 } ],
        "remarks": "OK"
    }
]
```

Below is the Desired format I would like to have in table format for the same above json O/P

```
sDate     | sName   | wCode | wDesc | grpType | W1 | W2 | W3 | W4 | W5 | W6 |
2019-08-30| Shift A | WCode | WCode | GType   |230 |240 |343 |343 |356 | 0  |
2019-08-30| Shift A |WCode  |WCode  |GType    |230 |240 |343 | 0  |  0 |  0 |
2019-08-30| Shift A |WCode  |WCode  |GType    |0   |240 |343 |343 |356 |356 |
```

OutPut JSON Format would be More or less(because in case of W1 to W6 shown above it may be something like "P1", "P5", "P9") looks like the below one

```
{
            "shiftDate": "2019-08-30T00:00:00",
            "shiftName": "Shift A",
            "workCenterCode": "WCode",
            "workCenterDesc": "WDesc",
            "groupType": "GType",
            "W1": 242.000
            "W2": 234.000
            "W3": 250.000
            "W4": 236.000
            "W5": 248.000
            "remarks": "OK"
}
```

So I have to format the `List<SPCRawDataDTO>` DTOs such that the Output should look like the above format in the UI Table.

Now how do I Convert the `List<SPCRawDataDTO>` in which `SPCRawDataDTO` itself having `List<SPCDynamicSpecValues>` to a `List<Anononimous type OBJ>`?

Comment: Are you want to convert from `SpecValue : PointValue`  key value object to flatten along with parent class fields `SPCRawDataDTO`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @user2932057, What you have said is correct, i want to flatten the `SpecValue : PointValue` to the parent class fields `SPCRawDataDTO`. btw i have edited the Question and added required JSON Format for the same. hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject) to dynamically add each specValue as property to the resulting object, for example:

```
private static object ToObj(SPCRawDataDTO src)
{
    var dest = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    dest.Add("ShiftDate", src.ShiftDate);
    dest.Add("ShiftName", src.ShiftName);
    // TODO: add all other properties
    for (var i = 0; i < src.SpecValues.Count; ++i)
    {
        dest.Add($"W{i + 1}", src.SpecValues[i].SpecValue);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

which could be called using:

```
List<SPCRawDataDTO> dtos = ... // TODO: the dtos
var result = dtos.Select(ToObj);
```

Comment: This is what i have been looking for, Thanks for the solution. 
This solution worked for my case.